# Gulp CJSX Error render compilation

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, gulp, preprocessor

I'm using gulp to compile a cjsx file (for Reacjs), but i have some trouble after compilation is done.

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('scripts', function ()   {
return gulp.src('dev/scripts/**/*.cjsx')
    .pipe($.cjsx({bare: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts/'))
    .pipe($.size()); 
});
```

component.cjsx

```
@Login = React.createClass
getInitialState: ->
    error: null

handleSubmit: (e) ->
    #do some thing

render: ->
    if @state.error
        error = <div>{this.state.error}</div>

    `<form className=loginForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {error}
        <input type="text" placeholder="emdsmmail" ref="email" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="password" ref="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>`
@Dashboard = React.createClass
render: ->
    <div>SomeText</div>
```

Then after render it's like that (i put just the end of the code) : 
component.js

```
  render: function() {
var error;
if (this.state.error) {
  error = React.createElement("div", null, this.state.error);
}
    return <form className=loginForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {error}
        <input type="text" placeholder="emdsmmail" ref="email" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="password" ref="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>;
}
});

this.Dashboard = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "SomeText");
}
});
```

If i use the direct command with the npm cjsx -c my-component.cjsx, it's work properly with quote ( ` ).

So first i try to save my quote ( `) but it's give me a bad result like you can see for the 'form'.

So i delete the quote ( ` ) like one the dashboard component to show what's happen, and it's works; but only if i don't use the quote like : ( " ) or ( ' ) for properties like the input on 'form'.

If someone can help me,
You give me a good help :)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fine solution, make 1 task like :
 .coffee (real .cjsx) -> .js (real .jsx) -> .js (real .js)

So my gulp file is like that :

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('scripts', function ()   {
return gulp.src('dev/scripts/**/*.coffee')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.coffee())
    .pipe($.react())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts'))
    .pipe($.size());
});
```

(ps : $ = gulp-load-plugin // coffee = gulp-coffee // react = gulp-react)